# How to clear firebird query cache?

Tags: database, firebird, database-administration

How do I clear the firebird query cache to execute my performance tests ?

The example in SqlServer [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1360/clearing-cache-for-sql-server-performance-testing/)

Tks

Comment: I don't think Firebird has a "Query Cache" it merely caches individual blocks of data. But never the result of a query.

Comment: Can be, but I still must to clean it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Andrei is correct -- Firebird heavily relies on the OS file system cache.  Firebird will cache a small amount of pages internally (check the buffers property on your database) however it's generally a very small amount of data.   Classic defaults to something like 75 pages?  I've seen suggestions of about 1000 pages elsewhere, which comes out to 8 or 16 MB depending on page size.

In lieu of restarting the OS to clear the file system cache, you could put your database on its own mount.  Then to completely clear the cache you could stop Firebird, unmount/mount the partition and start Firebird again.  That would invalidate the file system cache.

This shouldn't be too painful -- unlike other databases, Firebird does not have to scan the data files on start and replay transactions in a transaction log.  The translation log is essentially combined with the data file by using careful writes.

Answer (score 1):

Besides memory buffer for often accessed data pages Firebird relies on the OS file cache. Restarting server process one can empty the memory buffer but for clearing file cache, I'm afraid, you need to restart OS.

Comment: What you said make sense with I saw in operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think restarting the Firebird service is the easiest (only?) way.

Comment: What I noticed is that even restarting the service it works properly.